# Problems with uploading file using Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmitForm" class="col-md-12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="content" id="content">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-10">Submit</button>  
</form>
```

Here is my Vue code:

```
onSubmitForm: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var diplom = this.newDiploma;
    this.$http.post('/diplomas', diplom);
}

data:{
    newDiploma:{
        content:''
    }
```

controller:

```
public function add(Request $request){
        request()->file('content')->store('images');
}
```

I get is:

```
Call to a member function store() on null
```

Seems like controller gets no inputs from form

Comment: well currently you do not send any content. Your data contains an empty content property which isn't connected to your file input at all. You are sending { content : '' }

Comment: @FrankProvost, when i try to bind v-model to content and to input it gives me "File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead."

Comment: Is `diplom` instance of `FormData`?

Comment: and removing the binding completly should solve the problem then ;) ? It's exactly what it says. You need to listen to the chang event and handle the file on your own. Here's an example https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/